# How to return value on Meteor.call() in client?

Tags: javascript, twitter, meteor

So I've been using the twitter API w/MeteorJS and what I'm attempting to do is just display the screen name of the twitter user on the browser. This is what I have done so far:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'screenName': function() {
      T.get('search/tweets',
      {
        q:'#UCLA',
        count:1
      },
      function(err,data,response) {
        console.log(data.statuses[0].user.screen_name);
        return data.statuses[0].user.screen_name;
      }
    )
  }
});
```

So I call the method 'screenName' from my isClient side. I call it from my client side like this:

```
  var temp = Meteor.call('screenName');
```

On the server side, its printing out the correct value on console but it is not able to return that value. It keeps displaying undefined.

I am a javascript beginner so I might be making a mistake that I'm not seeing right away so if someone could please help me, I would highly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to place a function inside the call to be able to get the return.

```
Meteor.call(
    'screenName',
    function(error, result){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    }
);
```

You can read more in the documentation about the call function: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call

Comment: Hey, could you explain me like why we need to do this? Essentially, this is a callback function, correct? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes it is. From the documentation: On the client, if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a stub, call will return undefined, and you will have no way to get the return value of the method. That is because the client doesn't have fibers, so there is not actually any way it can block on the remote execution of a method.

Comment: What is a stub exactly and what is fiber? If you could link me to a place where I could possibly read about this, that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Fibers and threads blog post: https://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/fibers-and-threads-in-node-js-what-for/

Comment: Good explanation on fibers: https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/nodejs-introducing-fibers