# How to assign outer value from Meteor.call() in client?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

I have a similar situation as stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660369/how-to-return-value-on-meteor-call-in-client). Had defined a server Meteor method that receives an object that calls a third party library for exchange results. When calling with Meteor.call on the client side, I need to assign the results value to an outer variable. However, I am getting undefined as the way I am doing ( I guess it's because of the asynchronous behavior of the method) How can I improve the following code?

```
//Method on the client side (React.JS Component)
callRatesConvert(fromCurrency, toCurrency, amount) {
    const call = this.props.call;
    let resCall = 0; // Outer variable
    let settings = {};
    settings.fromCurrency = fromCurrency;
    settings.toCurrency = toCurrency;
    settings.amount = amount;
    settings.accuracy = 10;

//Calls Backend method API that returns res successfully
    call('rates.convert', settings, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
           //Shows UI Error to user
        } else if (res) { //res value is fetched from backend method properly
            resCall = res; // this is not being assigning properly
        }
    });
    console.log('resCall', resCall); //this prints 'undefined'
    return resCall;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn `callRatesConvert` into a function that returns a Promise. You can also use shorthand property assignment to reduce the syntax noise of your code if you want:

```
callRatesConvert(fromCurrency, toCurrency, amount) {
  const call = this.props.call;
  const settings = {
    fromCurrency,
    toCurrency ,
    amount,
    accuracy: 10,
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    call('rates.convert', settings, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        //Show Error UI to user
        reject(err);
      } else if (res) {
        resolve(res);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Then consume it with

```
someInstantiation.callRatesConvert(...)
  .then((resCall) => {
    // do something with the response
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

you have a problem there, not in the call, it is on your code, I'll add some notes.

```
//Method on the client side (React.JS Component)
callRatesConvert(fromCurrency, toCurrency, amount) {
    const call = this.props.call;
    let resCall = 0; // Outer variable
    let settings = {};
    settings.fromCurrency = fromCurrency;
    settings.toCurrency = toCurrency;
    settings.amount = amount;
    settings.accuracy = 10;

//Calls Backend method API that returns res succesfully
    call('rates.convert', settings, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
           //Show Error UI to user
        } else if (res) { //res value is fetched from backend method properly
            console.log('result from call', res) //this wont be undefined.
            resCall = res; //this is assigned but it takes some time because it is still fetching
        }
    });
    console.log('resCall', resCall); //this will print undefined because it is outside the call method, and it is not assigned yet.
    return resCall; // this obviously will be undefined.
    }
```

so one solution could be using the `Session` from meteor:

```
//Method on the client side (React.JS Component)
callRatesConvert(fromCurrency, toCurrency, amount) {
    const call = this.props.call;
    let resCall = 0; // Outer variable
    let settings = {};
    settings.fromCurrency = fromCurrency;
    settings.toCurrency = toCurrency;
    settings.amount = amount;
    settings.accuracy = 10;

//Calls Backend method API that returns res succesfully
    call('rates.convert', settings, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
           //Show Error UI to user
        } else if (res) { 
            resCall = res; 
            console.log('resCall', resCall); 
            Session.set("resCall", resCall)
        }
    });
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It works. However, I am avoiding to overuse Session sets. Seems that returning an ES6 promise works fine too.